# How to return 'this' object with an event handler in older browsers

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm trying to create a small javascript library for my private use.
Currently, I'm trying to create  `event` method to add event to one element or many elements.
The problem specifically pertaining in `IE 6, 7, 8`.
Everyone know if we do an event to many element, then when we write 'this' inside the callback function, mean the element that you click on it, for example using jquery.

```
$(".box").on('click', function(){
    $(this).html(); // get content of the element that clicked on it.
})
```

In my library `this` object works fine on modern browsers `ff, ch, op, saf, IE9+`, but on `IE 6,7,8` does not work.

**The following is the part that responsible for create an event in my library:**

```
event: function (event, callback, sync) {
    // if the user uses modern browser.    
    // 'this.length' to know how many elements (selector).
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        // if the selector more than one element
        if (this.length > 1) {
            while (this.length--) {
                this[this.length].addEventListener(event, callback, sync);
            }
        } else {
            this[0].addEventListener(event, callback, sync);
        }
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        if (this.length > 1) { 
            while (this.length--) {
                this[this.length].attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
            }
        } else {
            this[0].attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    }
    return this;
```

**The following is an example using my library to apply an event on several elements uses class named `box`.**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <p class="box">span</p>
    <p class="box">span 2</p>
    <p class="box">span 3</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
oo('.box').event('click', function () {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

The next code works only on the old browsers

```
oo('.box').event('click', function() {
    alert(window.event.srcElement.innerHTML);
});
```

`this.innerHTML` Mean when click on an element will get its content.
The previous example works fine in modern browsers, but on `IE 6, 7, 8` does not work, and give me `undefined`

Comment: I doubt $(this) is the problem!

Comment: `while (this.length--)` doesn't work (will emtpy your array and throw an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution of this problem in the following point:**

```
this[this.length].attachEvent('on' + event, function(){ callback.call(window.event.srcElement); });
```